# Network printer loses connection, but not its fault

Tags: router, lan, network-printer

tl;dr: What could cause a network printer to lose its connection besides the printer or router or cable between them?

I have had a Canon wired network laser printer for years with no issues, but after a point in time a new problem developed - sometimes when I or my husband tried to print (both PCs are Win7 if that matters) the printer driver would complain of a "network board error". Cycling power on the printer would fix it for the time being, but it would recur (usually the next day or so). After putting up with this for several months, we decided that the printer was dying and bought a new printer, a similar but newer model. But the new one did the same thing! I thought back and realized that it may have started happening at about the time I had simplified our home LAN from a wired router and a wireless access point to one robust wireless router (Netgear) that could do everything we needed. I tried a different network cable, but when that didn't solve it, I decided that the our Netgear router must be flaky. It was already out of warranty, so I bought yet another new router, this time a Buffalo. But... yup, you guessed it: The problem remains! It seems to happen after being idle for some time (a matter of hours, I think) - once we have printed something, we can print more with no issues.

The printer is on a fixed IP address (192.168.1.6) as is a NAS drive (192.168.1.3). The PCs are on DHCP, but the router is set to only assign addresses above 192.168.1.10, so as far as I know I'm not having address conflicts. I do have random interruptions to my internet connection (not obvious when just browsing, but enough to kill Skype and SSH), but that has been going on since long before the printer problem (the reason I changed the network layout was to try to fix that) and it shouldn't even be related to this anyway - the PCs and printer are simply on the internal LAN, and the printer is sitting on the shelf right above the router and is directly connected to one of its LAN ports with a short cable. I can't figure out what else to try! Any ideas?

EDITS: A suggested in the comments, I tested connecting the printer directly to my computer with a LAN cable for a week, and there were no problems, so it's definitely not the printer itself but something in the mysterious bowels of my LAN. I tried to use Wireshark as suggested in other comments, but it doesn't see the traffic between the router and printer (promiscuous mode doesn't work on Windows, apparently). The problem might be happening after some device goes to sleep and wakes up, or leaves the LAN and returns, but I haven't been able to identify a repeatable pattern.

Comment: If you still keep getting the "network board error" message even with the 2nd printer, I'm afraid but it sure has to be hardware issue with your printer network card. Have you tried another make of printer on your network...just to be sure the printer isn't faulty?

Comment: Have you tried connecting a computer directly to the printer to see if you have the same problem?  When attempting to identify a fault in a system, start with the most basic pieces needed to make it work. In this instance, you should only trouble shoot with a computer, the printer and a known good network cable.

Comment: @Immanuel I don't have another make of network printer, so I would have to buy one, and I already spent $700 for this one that appears to be a wasted expense. But I can call in a Canon repairman on warranty if necessary.

Comment: @OSol1tair3 Connecting directly with USB works fine, but I haven't tried using a network cable that way - I'll try and let you know (if it doesn't fail, it will take a couple days to know with some confidence, and during that time my computer will be without internet).

Comment: I discovered that I can leave my wireless adaptor connected to the web while my wired adaptor is connected to the printer, so I think I have been doing a test without being completely unplugged from the world. I waited about 30 hours before trying to print again. It worked fine, so unless accessing the web is causing my PC to shout out on both adaptors (which might keep the printer connection alive), my impression is that the problem does not occur when connecting directly.

Comment: It may well be that something is hosing your network. I recommend diagnosing that first. It could be malware, or bonjour, which I've seen nuke enterprise networks.  Start with running av scan, or testing printing with a single PC on the network. Try with both separately. If you're up for it, install wireshark, have a peek at the lan traffic.

Comment: have you contacted Canon support?

Comment: @Alex Atkinson: Can Bonjour cause a problem every day even if an Apple product is only on our LAN a few times a year when a friend with a Mac visits? On your other topics, AV checks have been done, and it fails even when only one PC is on the network. I guess Wireshark would be the next thing to try - I've never used it but I guess I could learn.

Comment: @OsakaWebbie - Bonjour has deviled me several times with broadcast storms. It's not the hardware, it's the software. Bonjour is the software. Kill it with fire. Yes, get to know wireshark. If there's an issue, especially in smaller environments it'll become evident rather quickly. With Bonjour for example, even on a floor of 80 pc's, 60-80% of the traffic that hit my interface had the same source and destination, which made it easy to spot. Look for large amounts of traffic going to, or from the same source. Good luck.

Comment: @Keltari: When we first got the new printer, I couldn't get it to connect at all at first, so I thought it was broken out-of-the-box. I called Canon and they came and looked at it. But I was not waiting long enough with the power off when recycling power - the service guy waited ten seconds, and that fixed it, so he went home. But then it died again the next day... :( We usually have to recycle with a 10-second pause the first time in a day that we print something. Since it works on my PC, I'm pretty sure it's a network problem.

Comment: @AlexAtkinson: Saved a short (one minute or so, 1282 total packets) Wireshark capture that I started while the printer was unreachable and continued while I recycled power on the printer to heal the connection. The other way around (catching the connection in the act of dying) would be better, but that would most likely take awhile - I don't know how long I can run a capture without it crippling something. Would you like to see the capture file? I don't know what to look for. I was surprised how much traffic there was from my PC to the printer with no print job (polling?).

Comment: I just realized something about my setup: WS is only seeing packets going to/from my PC, whereas the culprit is probably between the router (or some other device through the router) and the printer. Promiscuous mode is turned on in WS, but the rumor mill says it doesn't actually work on Windows (adaptors are hamstrung or something).

Comment: Rather than rebooting the printer, when the problem happens can you get it to come back online by disconnecting the ethernet plug and waiting the 10 seconds, then reconnecting? If not, try this with the PC. I have had routers decide to stop communicating on a port, presumably due to some firewall feature that claimed to be off in the router GUI but wasn't.

Comment: No, 10 sec. of uncabling (at either end - I tried both) does not fix it. (PC<->wifi connections have already repeatedly been redone, with no effect.) Once it gets stuck, only rebooting the printer works. But since the printer works fine directly connected to the PC, I still maintain that it's not the printer. Since the printer is under warranty and the repair guy makes house calls, I will probably see if he can figure out something. But I can't make it fail on demand, so it might be hard to troubleshoot while a guy is on the clock.